# What is the fastest way to write object in direct buffer?

Tags: java, serialization, nio, openmpi

I need write serialized object into ByteBuffer. What is the fastest way to made it without overhead copying and intermediate conversions?

I need to transfer a large object (more than 2GB) through the openmpi-java, that may use only direct buffers, and I want to take the ideas proposed as the basis.

Comment: Serialize it yourself.  Any kind of automated operation is going to be slower.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually; only the JVM itself has direct access to the bytes in memory that make up your object. Thus no matter what kind serialization tool you will be selecting, a certain amount of conversions and copying **must** happen.

Because you are actually asking to take fields of your objects, and depending on meta information, **copy** their content into some bytes. That simply can't work without copying/conversions.

Besides; I am wondering if you are looking at the "correct" problem here. Serialization is by itself a costly operation. There are many ways to do it; and they have vastly different properties.

What I am saying is: are you sure you should be worried about performance? Or maybe, you spent more time thinking about the long-term consequences of using this or that serialization technique. Or the security risks involved in (de)serialization of objects?

Long story short: what makes you think that **performance** is an issue?

Answer (score 0):

What I do is create an OutputStream which wraps a ByteBuffer. Pass the OutputStream to your favourite serialization tool. I have a replacement for ByteBuffer which supports this, but it's easy to add.

BTW Just about any serialization library is faster than standard Java Serialization.